# Why am I not seeing logs when using a Corretto based Spring Boot Docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, logging, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create a Spring Boot app as an ECS service. I tried to use the Corretto image but I am still not seeing logs in the task. How do I configure the task or dockerfile to be able to properly see the logs?

My Dockerfile

```
# Use the Oracle Java 20 JDK as the base image
FROM amazoncorretto:20

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the JAR file into the container
COPY build/libs/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Set the command to run when the container starts
CMD ["java", "-jar", "backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**Entire Task Def**

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "..../cbusha-backend-task:3",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "cbusha-be",
            "image": "....dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ecomm-backend",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "cbusha-backend-task",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 3,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "3072",
    "registeredAt": "2023-07-09T15:08:35.980Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::...:root",
    "tags": []
}
```

This is the permission on `ecsTaskExecutionRole`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It entirely depends on how you are writing your logs. Have you configured your logging to go to STDOUT and STDERR? Or are you writing logs to a log file?

Comment: Just says "console" so based off of Google that is STDOUT  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.x/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.console-output

Comment: Added Spring Boot to title to make this clearer

Comment: Do you see the logs in the docker console when you run the same docker image locally? Is it only on ECS that you don't see the logs? Where exactly are you looking for the logs in AWS?

Comment: I don't run it in docker locally but I do when I run gradle bootRun. My buddy brought up a good point about confirm IAM permissions so I am going to look into that

Comment: I added 'CloudWatchLogsFullAccess' to 'ecsTaskExecutionRole' but no dice

Comment: "I don't run it in docker locally but I do when I run gradle bootRun." Just because you don't _normally_ run the app using Docker locally doesn't mean you shouldn't at least test the Docker image locally to determine if this is an AWS issue or something else. We would like to help you here, but you need to take the necessary debugging steps on your end.

Comment: "My buddy brought up a good point about confirm IAM permissions so I am going to look into that" Are you seeing AWS CloudWatch Log groups and log streams get created, or not? That would tell you if the IAM permissions are wrong. That's also why I asked where exactly in AWS you are looking for logs.

Comment: @MarkB I can hit the endpoint so I know the image is working. I can confirm locally that it is writing the the STDOUT but it will take time. As for log groups I do not see the log groups getting created.

Comment: You need to show your ECS Task definition JSON representation in your question for further help. You are most likely missing a log configuration, or an IAM role permission.

Comment: Sure I will add the definition JSON. The IAM role should be added for the task def so I no longer think it is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was 2 part, first I needed to add this to install the log driver on my docker image...

```
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y python3
# Install awslogs
RUN pip3 install awscli awslogs
```

Next I had to go into my task definition and add the following...

```
{
  "family": "cbusha-backend-task",
  ...
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      ...
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "your-log-group-name",
          "awslogs-region": "your-aws-region",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "your-stream-prefix"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And now I am seeing the logs in cloudwatch!

If you are coming to this answer without fully reading the question make sure your Task Definition's "Task Execution Role" has the CloudWatch Logs IAM permission as well.